# ASP.net Textbox that adds "ING"

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a textbox for verbs and I want it to auto add "ing" to any word the user tries typing in that box if its not there.  Is this possible?  And how?

My verb textbox is:

```
tbVerb
```

Comment: There are a few forms about this. http://www.edufind.com/english-grammar/ing-forms/ Have you tried _anything_ to solve this by the way?

Comment: Taking a simple verb such as "read" where adding "ing" does indeed give the expected result, how do you see the user typing that? The user starts "r". At that point, the word doesn't end with "ing", so your question suggests you want to add "ing" to get "ring". Now the user types "e". Do you get "reing"? Do you get "ringe"? Do you get "re" (to which the same transformation gets applied again)? Have you thought about any of that?

Comment: @hvd maybe he wants to do it when the user is pushing a button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void tbVerb_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!tbVerb.Text.EndsWith("ing"))
       tbVerb.Text += "ing";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `TextChanged` Event:

```
private void tbVerb_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // add your value to checkbox
    // this code is WinForms
    // tbVerb.Text = tbVerb.Text + "ing";
}
```

Comment: Adding just `ing` does not solve this. For example; `swim` would be `swimming` not `swiming`.

Comment: @SonerGönül You're absolutely right, but that seems like it should be a comment on the question, not this answer. It's the question that talks about adding "ing".

Answer (score 1):

Think this should do what you want.

```
if(textbox.text.substring(textbox.text.lenght-3) != "ing")
   textbox.text += "ing";
```

But you will need a validate or event as the guy in the other answer suggests.